# How write SQL Query in Marklogic JAVA API using WHERE IN clause?

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-optic-api

I am using Marklogic Optic Java API as follows :-

```
ModifyPlan plan = p.fromView(SchemaName, ViewName)
              .where(p.eq(p.col("COL1"), strColValue))
              .select(colSeq);
```

Now I have list of data & I need use "WHERE IN" clause for this query.

```
select * from table where col in ('val1', 'val2'.....,'valn');
```

Could anyone please tell me how to do this using marklogic Java API.

Thanks & Regards,

Renuka Patil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to use SQL on Marklogic DB using Java is JDBC.You can perform following steps:

1. **Step 1:**

Download JDBC driver from: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.4.jar 
 & Reference it in your Java Project.

2. **Step 2:**

Setup ODBC server on Marklogic DB as described in : https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/odbc
(Remember to select your correct DB in this step & for this example, change Auth type to Basic)

3. **Step 3:**

Sample Java code can be as follow:

```
try {
            Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://MYHOST:PORT/?preferQueryMode=simple","USER","PWD");
            Statement stmt = conn1.createStatement();
            String sqlstmt = "select SCHEMA.VIEW.COLUMN1, VSCHEMA.VIEW.COLUMN2, SCHEMA.VIEW.COLUMN3 from SCHEMA.VIEW where SCHEMA.VIEW.COLUMN4 in ('VAL1', 'VAL2', 'VAL3')";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlstmt);
            while(rs.next()){ 
                String c1= rs.getString("COLUMN1"); 
                String c2= rs.getString("COLUMN2");
                System.out.println("COL1:"+c1);
                System.out.println("COL2:"+c2);
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note:

1. The code shown above is just to show the possibility of connection & not industrialized version. Hence should be refactored while using
   as per coding gudelines like removing hardcoding & use of binded queries, etc
2. Port Number is one which was used for ODBC server setup in
   Marklogic.

Hope it helps you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way to do that is to just pass in a sequence of strings on the right hand side of the join condition:

```
ModifyPlan plan = p.fromView(SchemaName, ViewName)
    .where(p.eq(p.col("COL1"), p.xs.stringSeq("val1", "val2",...,"valn")))
    .select(colSeq);
```

Answer (score -1):

I see `p.xs.stringSeq` is deprecated. The documentation is preferring us to use as below:

```
{
    ModifyPlan plan = p.fromView(SchemaName, ViewName)
                       .where(p.eq(p.col("COL1"), 
                               p.seq(p.xs.string("val"),p.xs.string("val2"))))
                       .select(colSeq);
}
```

I changed from `p.xs.stringSeq` to `p.seq`